# SQL-запрос на 2 таблицы

Tags: mysql, php, kohana, sql

Ребята, составляю сложный sql-запрос через query builder в kohana (но это не столь важно), и не получается сделать его хорошо, выходит много костылей и т.п. Так вот, хотелось бы сделать один запрос на 2 таблицы и обработать его в php, при этом сделав запрос оптимальнее.

Имеется 2 таблицы: **questions** (Вопросы) и **answers** (Список ответов для вопросов). 
*P.S. Также есть еще таблица самих тестов, в которые включаются эти вопросы с ответами.*
Делается SQL-запрос и в PHP обрабатывается следующим видом:

**Пример.**

1.Вопрос номер 1.

— Ответ первый.

— Ответ второй.

2.Вопрос номер 2.

— Ответ первый для 2 вопроса.

— Ответ второй для 2 вопроса.

— Ответ третий для 2 вопроса.

.......

Таким образом должно, по идее, получиться **2 foreach()**, которые вложены друг в друга:

1. Первый цикл выводит **все вопросы для этого теста**.
2. Второй цикл выводит **все ответы для одного вопроса* в этом тесте.

Если использовать LEFT JOIN, то делается большое количество лишних данных (например: повторение самого вопроса для каждого ответа). И еще приходится лепить костыли для PHP, чтобы корректно отобразить.
Еще можно делать запросы к ответам в первом foreach, когда выводим вопросы, но, как мне известно, запросы в цикле — плохая практика.

Так вот, можно ли такой запрос написать? И если можно, то как?
По моим представлениям, я думаю, что должно получиться что-то вроде этого, для обработки:

*$question->name — Текст вопроса.*

*$question->answer->value - Текст ответа для текущего вопроса.*

**P.S. Использовать ORM — не предлагать.** Использую query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, красиво эту задачу не решить (без дополнительных запросов и перемешивания вопросов и ответов). Кажется, это просто не укладывается в реляционную модель данных.

Считается, что можно несколько ускорить однотипные запросы (запросы ответов для вопросов), используя `prepared statements` (`подготовленные запросы`). Не проверял.

Но если время важно, то лучше использовать `join` и дополнительную логику в php. Думаю, будет быстрее.

В конце концов можно реализовать оба варианта (если грубыми мазками, то делов-то не много) и посмотреть, какой лучше работает.